# How can I manipulate values in DatePicker control rendered as UIDatePickerContentView using Xamarin UITest on iOS App

Tags: ios, xamarin, datepicker, uitest

I have a DatePicker that is being rendered as UIDatePickerContentView that I need to manipulate in an autometed test to set the date. REPL tree freezes when the Date Picker is displayed so groping in the dark to understand what is in the model. I've been able to interrogate a bit using the following ...

```
>>> app.Query(c => c.Raw("UIDatePickerContentView"))                                                                                       
Query for Raw("UIDatePickerContentView") gave 23 results.   
    [0] {
        Id => null,
        Description => "<UIDatePickerContentView: 0x7f99c3fc1e80; frame = (0 0; 132 32); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000713c580>>",
        Rect => {                                                                                                                          
            Width => 126.63,
            Height => 7.12,
            X => 221.83,
            Y => 193.18,
            CenterX => 285.15,
            CenterY => 196.74
        },
        Label => "September",
        Text => null,
        Class => "UIDatePickerContentView",
        Enabled => true
    },
    [1] {
        Id => null,
        Description => "<UIDatePickerContentView: 0x7f99cbc3e6a0; frame = (0 0; 132 32); layer = <CALayer: 0x600003b49ca0>>",
        Rect => {
            Width => 130.03,
            Height => 19.39,
            X => 218.59,
            Y => 200.64,
            CenterX => 283.6,
            CenterY => 210.33
        },
        Label => "October",
        Text => null,
        Class => "UIDatePickerContentView",
        Enabled => true
```

... but cannot find any info about backdoor methods on this Class that can be Invoked.

I could write a hacky method to set things but I'm sure there must be a nicer way to set the date. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Stack Trace:

```
Execution failed with exception: System.Net.WebException: GET Failed           
  at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.HandleHttpError (System.String method, System.Exception exception, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy) [0x0003c] in <12fefce8c9d24a03847e99ca872ebbec>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.Request (System.String method, System.String endpoint, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, System.Nullable`1[T] timeOut) [0x00155] in <12fefce8c9d24a03847e99ca872ebbec>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient.Get (System.String endpoint, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.ExceptionPolicy exceptionPolicy, System.Nullable`1[T] timeOut) [0x00000] in <12fefce8c9d24a03847e99ca872ebbec>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.HttpCalabashConnection.Dump () [0x00000] in <12fefce8c9d24a03847e99ca872ebbec>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSGestures.Dump () [0x00000] in <12fefce8c9d24a03847e99ca872ebbec>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.TreePrintHelper.PrintTree (Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ITreePrinter treePrinter) [0x00006] in <12fefce8c9d24a03847e99ca872ebbec>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppPrintHelper.Tree (System.Nullable`1[T] console) [0x0001c] in <12fefce8c9d24a03847e99ca872ebbec>:0 
  at <InteractiveExpressionClass>.Host (System.Object& $retval) [0x00010] in <7453cce1cdcc4fe4afe263a530a7fb22>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Evaluate (System.String input, System.Object& result, System.Boolean& result_set) [0x0003e] in <e5610ebfe8c34526a8158db3c89186d4>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.Evaluation.MonoCSharpReplEngine.Evaluate (System.String line) [0x00017] in <36fced282c0c46b3875df4694444ba35>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.Repl.ReplFacade.RunCode (System.String code) [0x00026] in <b735ea7cb64e4833abf7213ad2e5f225>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.PromptHandler.PrintTree () [0x00000] in <b735ea7cb64e4833abf7213ad2e5f225>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.PromptHandler.HandleInput (System.ConsoleKeyInfo key) [0x00072] in <b735ea7cb64e4833abf7213ad2e5f225>:0 
  at Xamarin.UITest.Repl.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00177] in <b735ea7cb64e4833abf7213ad2e5f225>:0 
Press any key to exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up looking for an elegant solution to the problem and resorted to using DragCoordinates in the DatePicker UI widget to set the individual date elements to the desired values. This meant first working out X and Y for all the parts and moving each one one step at a time after determining the number of steps required to change "March" to "June" for example - 3 steps. It works.